# Passing multiple jvm arguments containg spaces in one bash variable

Tags: bash, variables

I have a small java program:

```
    public class Test {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("A: " + System.getProperty("A"));
        System.out.println("B: " + System.getProperty("B"));
      }
    }
```

It works like this:

```
    # java -DA="A B" -DB="B A" Test
    A: A B
    B: B A
```

Now let's assume that someone is going to execute my program from bash like this, and I have no way to change it:

```
# java "$PARAMS" Test
```

I have the values of A and B in bash variables, both of them containing spaces, like this:

```
    # A="A B"
    # B="B A"
```

how can I set the value of the PARAMS variable so that it would work fine?

I've tried this:

```
    # PARAMS="-DA=\"$A\" -DB=\"$B\""
    # echo $PARAMS
    -DA="A B" -DB="B A"
```

It seems that everything is fine, the value of $PARAMS is exactly the same as in the example above, but this is what I get:

```
    # set -x; java "$PARAMS" Test; set +x
    + set -x
    + java '-DA="A B" -DB="B A"' Test
    A: "A B" -DB="B A"
    B: null
    + set +x
```

So upon evaluating the PARAMS variable it is surrounded by single quotes thus java interprets it as a single variable A = '"A B" -DB="B A"'

So the question is how can I set the value of PARAMS using A and B to be evaluated as expected?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a="java $PARAMS Test"
eval "$a"
```

or

```
java "$PARAMS" Test
```

### After your comment

As I see you need to use `eval` in this situation! This is a bash feature.
I depict your bash problem with an `awk` calling:

```
cat test
BEGIN {printf("A: %s\nB: %s\n", a, b);}   # this is an awk script

awk -v a="A B" -v b="B A" -f test         # normal usage this test
A: A B
B: B A

par="-v a=\"A B\" -v b=\"B A\""
echo $par                                 # $par is ok
-v a="A B" -v b="B A"

awk "$par" -f test                        # usage of $par
awk: improper assignment: -v  a="A B" -v b="B A"   ###  Error

eval awk $par -f test                     # with eval ok
A: A B
B: B A    

set -x; awk "$par" -f test; set +x        # with trace
+ awk '-v a="A B" -v b="B A"' -f test
awk: improper assignment: -v  a="A B" -v b="B A"
+ set +x
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the command that will be executed is indeed in the format

'java "$PARAMS" Test'

and it can not be altered - I've modified the question, it's still not working this way. Using eval would help but I can't change the way it is executed.